# Sorting list containing multiple datatypes in Python

Tags: python, list

how to sort a list containing multiple datatypes in python 3.4?
for example:-
lixt=["Tak","jil","son",54,84]
lixt.sort()

Error:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

please help with the proper solution

Comment: Can you tell us, is `"son"` greater or smaller than `54`?

Comment: just use sorted

Comment: Write a function that take an item as an argument and returns `str(item)`. Then use that as the key function for the sort. ... [Sorting HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 2):

use `sorted(your_list, key=str)` for simple cases when you can sort by the string representation of the item

```
l = ["Tak","jil","son",54,84]
sorted(l, key=str)
```

output: `[54, 84, 'Tak', 'jil', 'son']`

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` takes three arguments: an iterable, a key and reverse i.e `sorted(iterable, [key=None], [reverse=False])`. The `key` argument allows you define a function which can be called to compare the values of items in the iterable. Some examples are given below:

```
# notice the function name is supplied without brackets
sorted(["Eva", "eva", "string", "Aaron"], key=str.lower)

# the same result using lambda
sorted(["Eva", "eva", "string", "Aaron"], key=lambda x: x.lower())

# comparing by the second element in a tuple: (name, age)
name_ages = [("Eva", 12), ("Tom", 14), ("Gerald", 4)]
# output is [('Gerald', 4), ('Eva', 12), ('Tom', 14)]
sorted(name_ages, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Using `lambdas` or by defining functions of your own, the sorted function is very versatile.

**NB:** Use can also use the `key` argument in `list.sort()`